# Rotation matrix around one coordinate in N dimensions

Tags: matrices, rotations

Probably a very simple question: Given the standard Cartesian coordinate matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\
 & 1 & \\
 &  &  1\\
 &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  & 1\\
 &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & .\\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

what is the matrix which is the extension of "basic rotations" to n-dimensions, as shown [[in Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) 
for 3 dimensions.

And say we wish to rotate by some arbitrary order around **several** coordinates $k$ by $\theta$ -  would the rotation matrix then simply be the multiplication of such $k$ matrices as above?

Comment: What do you mean by "rotates around only one coordinate"?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I mean basic rotation, around one axis (coordinate) of the system, as here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: @JimmyK4542 - i edited the question

Comment: Google "rotation in n dimensions", there's plenty of stuff about it on the web.

Comment: @GDumphart i'd appreciate a specific reference.